# why does strel failed in MATLAB Coder

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

Using MATLAB Coder in 2019b, the following line:

```
se = strel('line',20,85);
```

that MATLAB Coder is unable to effectively describe:

1.All inputs must be constant.

2.Function call failed

why is Coder having difficulty in `strel`?

does matlab coder support `strel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB Coder does support strel. I tried the following simple example in R2019b and noticed it worked.

```
% Function foo.m
function y = foo
    se = strel('line',20,85);
    y = numel(se.Neighborhood);
end

% Codegen command in command window
>> codegen foo -report
```

From the error messages you posted, it looks like your inputs to strel are not constant, which is why codegen is failing. Refer to the section on C/C++ code generation section in the documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html which states the following:

> Usage notes and limitations:
>
> - strel supports the generation of C code (requires MATLAB® Coder™). For more information, see [Code Generation for Image Processing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/code-generation-for-image-processing.html).
> - All input arguments must be compile-time constants.
> - The methods associated with strel objects are not supported in code generation.
> - Arrays of strel objects are not supported.

Example showing imerode based on comment:

```
% Function foo.m
function y = foo(edgeimg)
    se = strel('line',20,85);
    y = imerode(edgeimg, se.Neighborhood);
end

% Codegen command in command window
% The image must be 2D or 3D according to doc
>> edgeimg = imread('blah.png'); 
>> codegen foo -args edgeimg -report
```

Comment: thank you 
it solve the problem of strel
but when i add imrode code after strel 
MATLAB Coder has the same problem like: 
    All inputs must be constant.  and  Function call failed.
the following line:
se1 = strel('line',20,85);
zz1 = imerode(edgeimg,se1.Neighborhood); 

so is that any problem in imerode?

Comment: The problem is with your inputs to these functions. Please read the limitations in the C/C++ code generation section for each of these functions carefully. From the errors you are sharing, it looks like your inputs are not compile time constants. I've edited my original post showing a possible way of using imerode.